# The theory of connected graphs is not axiomatizable at the first order

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

I am asked to solve the following excercise:

> - Show that the theory of acyclic graphs is axiomatizable at the first order.
> - Call a graph connected if any two vertexes are connected are linked by a finite path. Show that the theory of connected graphs is not axiomatizable at the first order.

So, I fix a first order language $\mathscr{L}=\{E\}$.

For the first point I simply thought to exploit an infinite axiom schema:
$\lnot Ax(n)\; n\in\omega$="there does not exist a closed path of length n" which I would formalize with
$Ax(n)=\exists x_1\exists x_2...\exists x_n(\bigwedge_{i,j=1}^{n-1}\lnot(x_i=x_j)\wedge (x_n=x_1)\wedge (x_iEx_{i+1}))$
Is this correct?

I am a bit clueless about the second point. I understand that we should add two logical constants, ro be interpreted in $v_1,v_2$ and an infinite axiom schema assuring this two vertexes are distinct and not linked by a finite path, but I cannot find such a system of axioms.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Compactness, as Olivier says, is a nice way to show the second, but another fun way is to use an [ultrapower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct). It's easy to start from an infinite connected graph and form an ultrapower, which will be elementarily equivalent, that is not connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first point is correct. For the second point, you need to use **compactness theorem**.

Assume for contradiction that there's a theory $T$ whose models are precisely the connected graphs. Then, for each $n$, the graph $G_n$ with vertices $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and edges $\{(v_i,v_{i+1}) \big| 1\leqslant i < n\}$ is a model of $T$.

Now add two constant symbols $b$ and $c$ to your language : $\mathscr{L}':=\{E,b,c\}$. For each $n>2$, interpret $b$ by $v_1$ and $c$ by $v_n$ in $G_n$. Then 
$$G_n \models (b \neq c)\wedge \neg E(b,c) \wedge \bigwedge_{k < n-2} \Big(\underbrace{\neg \exists x_2,\dots x_{k+1} \big(E(b,x_2) \wedge \bigwedge_{i=2}^{k}E(x_i,x_{i+1})\wedge E(x_{k+1},c)}_{=:\varphi_k}\big) \ \Big)$$

In an ultraproduct $G$ of the $G_n$s by a non trivial ultrafilter of subsets of $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0,1,2\}$, you get $G\models T$, but $b$ and $c$ are not connected since for every $n$, you have $G\models (b \neq c)\wedge \neg E(b,c) \wedge \varphi_n$.
That's a contradiction : no such $T$ exists.

Comment: Actually, I cannot see why $G_n\models\bigwedge_{k < n-2} \Big(\underbrace{\neg \exists x_2,\dots x_{k+1} \big(E(b,x_2) \wedge \bigwedge_{i=2}^{k}E(x_i,x_{i+1})\wedge E(x_{k+1},c)}_{=:\varphi_k}\big) \ \Big)$, which should formalise 'there is not a a path of length at most n-2 connecting b and c', if $G_n$ is the linear graph with $n$ vertexes. Moreover, in the last line shouldn't it be $\phi_n$, rather that $\lnot\phi_n$. Excuse me, probably it is me messing with something.

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta The only path connecting $b$ and $c$ in $G_n$ is of length $n-1$. For the last line, you are right, it's $\varphi_n$ instead of $\neg \varphi_n$. I'll edit that.

Comment: @Olivier Roche: why couldn't there be an infinite path from $b$ to $c$?

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett Infinite path do exist in general , BUT if you take any two edges $x, y$ of a graph, a path from $x$ to $y$ is necessarily finite.

Comment: To see why, index  the edges of a path from $x$ to $y$  starting with $x_0 :=x$, $x_1$ the edge connected to $x_0$ and so on by transfinite induction. Now there must be some $\alpha$ such that $y = x_\alpha$. Notice that we can also index those edges from $y$ to $x$ starting with $y_0 := y$. If $\alpha$ were infinite, the sequence $y_0, y_1, \dots$ would provide an infinite descending chain, a contradiction!

Comment: Or, to put it in a nut shell : if you have an infinite path starting with $x$, who is going to be the last element?